Unable to Play any Audio File from Cached File - Media/Exo Player
I am trying to record the audio using MediaRecorder API of android and save the audio file in the cache directory of the app. The audio file gets saved perfectly into the cache dir and is working fine on my system when I extract it manually, but I am getting this whenever I try to play it using the URI of the file -

Source Error from ExoPlayer

java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1 from MediaPlayer


How I am recording the audio:
    private fun startRecording() {
        recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
            setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
            setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
            setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
            setOutputFile(File(
                cacheDir.absolutePath, "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.3gpp"
            ).absolutePath.also {
                audioFilePath = it
            })
            try {
                prepare()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                toast(getString(R.string.error_loading_data))
                binding.micLayout.clearFocus()
            }
            start()
        }
    }

I am able to successfully upload it to Firebase Storage like this:
    private fun processRecording() {
        val audioFile = File(audioFilePath!!)
        Log.d("Path>>", audioFilePath!!)
        if (audioFile.exists()) {
            val audioBytes = audioFile.readBytes()
            playRecording(Uri.fromFile(audioFile))
            FireRef.storageRef.child("ChatAudios/").child(audioFile.name).putBytes(audioBytes)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    val url = it.storage.downloadUrl
                    url.addOnCompleteListener { link ->
                        if (link.isSuccessful) {
                            Log.d("URL>", link.result.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

How I am trying to play it using MediaPlayer:
    private fun playRecording(uri: Uri) {
        MediaPlayer().apply {
            setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .build()
            )
            setDataSource(applicationContext, uri)
            prepare()
            start()
        }
    }

However, ExoPlayer plays it for the First time, but starts throwing Source Error next time (restarting the app works). ExoPlayer Implementation:
    private fun playRecording(uri: Uri) {
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(applicationContext).build()
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
        exoPlayer.apply {
            setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            prepare()
            play()
            addListener(object : Player.Listener {
                override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                    if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
                        exoPlayer.release()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks!

There's a) no stack-trace and b) with high probability you're calling prepare() twice, without calling release() in between. The question also appears to be duplicate. Please search before asking.

@MartinZeitler thank you for answering, I was actually trying to play the recording before releasing the MediaRecorder, now I am able to get the playback smoothly.
